# Conditionally adding a property in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I'd like to conditionally add a property to an object (or maybe I mean a class - I am unsure of the actual semantics in TypeScript).

```
import IMetadata from './metadata-interface';

export default class MetaData {

    [idx: string]: IMetadata;

    public 'foo' = {
        name: 'foo',
    } as IMetadata;

    public 'bar' = {
        name: 'bar',
    } as IMetadata;
};
```

But how do I conditionally add bar to the object? Can I do something like:

```
export default class MetaData {

    [idx: string]: IMetadata;

    public 'foo' = {
        name: 'foo',
    } as IMetadata;

    if(condition) {
      public 'bar' = {
          name: 'bar',
      } as IMetadata;
    }
};
```

Comment: "or maybe I mean a class". What's your goal here? Class and object are the same concepts like in other class-based languages. Do you really want to have conditional logic in constructing a class definition?

Comment: "Do you really want to have conditional logic in constructing a class definition?" Yes. I come from JavaScript (I am quite experienced with it). I am a total beginner with TypeScript.

Comment: I'm quite sure this is not possible, but could you elaborate on your use-case? I'm not totally convinced that you are actually looking for something like C# preprocessor directives here :)

Comment: So as you accepted Ryans answer, I guess you wanted to add a property to an object through a class definition and that you didn't mind the class always having that property defined as optional.

Comment: @Alex, yes. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an `if` statement:

```
export default class MetaData {

    [idx: string]: IMetadata;

    public 'foo' = {
        name: 'foo',
    } as IMetadata;

    public 'bar'?: IMetadata;

    constructor(condition: boolean) {
        if (condition) {
            this.bar = {
                name: 'bar',
            };
        }
    }
}
```